# Why should I bind req and res to cls.Namespace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, continuation-local-storage

This is common approach of using cls-hooked.

I don't know why this is really necessary for after.

```
return function clsifyMiddleware(req, res, next) {
        ns.bindEmitter(req);
        ns.bindEmitter(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in case of an asynchronous error, you can have the request context. See https://blog.besson.co/nodejs_async_hooks_to_get_per_request_context/ (async_hooks is a potential replacement for cls-hooked)